# Debugging tests written with Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

When isolating a root cause of a failing test written in Python or Java, I use a debugger built in my IDE (e.g., Intellij) to debug it.

Is the same possible for [Robot](http://robotframework.org/) tests?

Particularly, what's a support for debugging Robot tests in IDEA Intellij?

I wonder because I found Robot tests are a mix of both `.robot` and `.py` / `.java` fies.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357271/debug-robot-framework-tests-from-pycharm

Answer (score 3):

The Eclipse plugin called RED ([[GitHub][1](https://github.com/nokia/red)](https://github.com/nokia/red)) has support for the standard debugger.

[image]

More information can be found in the [RED GitHub Help pages](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/).

Comment: So no support for Intellij?

Comment: No, IntelliJ is not supported. The team does not have the capacity to support multiple IDE platforms. The approach they took _should_ be compatible, but a significant development effort is still needed for the IDE specific parts.